# 'for' vs. 'in' - which is faster?

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, for-loop

In my project, it's important to know if

```
for i in a_list:
    if i == "foo":
        do stuff
        break
```

Is much slower than:

```
if "foo" in a_list:
    do stuff
```

Is it?

Comment: Well, obviously your example using `in` is faster: You don't even short-circuit by `break`ing the loop once the item is found. There's simply no point in worrying about low-level performance metrics when you make massive high-level mistakes like that.

Comment: With the information you give, nobody would use the first methode, cause the second one is shorter, faster and easier to read.

Comment: Those two code snippets do not do the same thing, except in the case where there will only ever be either zero or one `'foo'`s in `a_list`.

Comment: @LukasGraf That's true, I forgot to write that in there. But it's only an example, obvously not my original code, I think it still makes sense to think about such things.

Comment: @Daniel I know, but why should I care? As you said, I haven't given much information. I have my reasons to ask that.

Answer (score 5):

First, any performance question is best answered by actually measuring the code.  Use timeit or a profiler to see which option is faster.

Second, in your two code samples, the if will be faster because they are doing the same work, but in the if, the work is done in C, while in the for, it's done in Python. (Assuming you add the break to the loop version to stop when you find the element).

Third, if you are concerned about speed, perhaps you don't want a list at all, but a set.  To find an element in a list, you have to examine each element in turn, which is an O(n) operation (if the list doubles in length, the operation will double in time).  In a set, it is O(1), finding an element takes the same amount of time no matter how large the set gets.

Answer (score -3):

**Yes it is.**

Here are my test-results:

```
test_list = [i for i in range(10000000)]

cProfile.run("if 9999999 in test_list: pass")
[...] total time: 0.152s

cProfile.run("for i in test_list: \n if i==9999999: pass"
[...] total time: 0.555s
```

Too bad.